# Unexpected call to method or property access. Only in IE8

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

The following error occurs only in `IE8`...Works in `Chrome` and `Firefox` can't test IE9 as I have recently downgraded for testing purposes.

> Unexpected call to method or property access.

### Call Stack

**Relevant Code marked with *\\Call occurs here***

*Debug values from IE Debugger...:*
_frames = object/function
callback = object/function
callbackTarget = object/function
callbackArg = undefined

```
ko.dependencyDetection = (function () {
    var _frames = [];

    return {
        begin: function (callback) {
            _frames.push({ callback: callback, distinctDependencies:[] });
        },

        end: function () {
            _frames.pop();
        },

        registerDependency: function (subscribable) {
            if (!ko.isSubscribable(subscribable))
                throw new Error("Only subscribable things can act as dependencies");
            if (_frames.length > 0) {
                var topFrame = _frames[_frames.length - 1];
                if (!topFrame || ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(topFrame.distinctDependencies, subscribable) >= 0)
                    return;
                topFrame.distinctDependencies.push(subscribable);
                topFrame.callback(subscribable);
            }
        },

        ignore: function(callback, callbackTarget, callbackArgs) {
            try {
                _frames.push(null);
                return callback.apply(callbackTarget, callbackArgs || []);
            }
            //Call occurs here
            //Error occurs here since there isn't a catch and the try is failing.
            finally {
                _frames.pop();
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

**Called From:**

```
"notifySubscribers": function (valueToNotify, event) {
    event = event || defaultEvent;
    if (this._subscriptions[event]) {
        //Call occurs here
        ko.dependencyDetection.ignore(function() {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this._subscriptions[event].slice(0), function (subscription) {
                // In case a subscription was disposed during the arrayForEach cycle, check
                // for isDisposed on each subscription before invoking its callback
                if (subscription && (subscription.isDisposed !== true))
                    subscription.callback(valueToNotify);
            });
        }, this);
    }
},
```

**Called From:**

```
ko.observable = function (initialValue) {
    var _latestValue = initialValue;

    function observable() {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            // Write

            // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
            if ((!observable['equalityComparer']) || !observable['equalityComparer'](_latestValue, arguments[0])) {
                observable.valueWillMutate();
                _latestValue = arguments[0];
                if (DEBUG) observable._latestValue = _latestValue;
                observable.valueHasMutated();
            }
            return this; // Permits chained assignments
        }
        else {
            // Read
            ko.dependencyDetection.registerDependency(observable); // The caller only needs to be notified of changes if they did a "read" operation
            return _latestValue;
        }
    }
    if (DEBUG) observable._latestValue = _latestValue;
    ko.subscribable.call(observable);
    observable.peek = function() { return _latestValue };
    //call occurs here
    observable.valueHasMutated = function () { observable["notifySubscribers"](_latestValue); }
    observable.valueWillMutate = function () { observable["notifySubscribers"](_latestValue, "beforeChange"); }
    ko.utils.extend(observable, ko.observable['fn']);

    ko.exportProperty(observable, 'peek', observable.peek);
    ko.exportProperty(observable, "valueHasMutated", observable.valueHasMutated);
    ko.exportProperty(observable, "valueWillMutate", observable.valueWillMutate);

    return observable;
}
```

**Called From:**

```
ko.observable = function (initialValue) {
    var _latestValue = initialValue;

    function observable() {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            // Write

            // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
            if ((!observable['equalityComparer']) || !observable['equalityComparer'](_latestValue, arguments[0])) {
                observable.valueWillMutate();
                _latestValue = arguments[0];
                if (DEBUG) observable._latestValue = _latestValue;
                //Call occurs here
                observable.valueHasMutated();
            }
            return this; // Permits chained assignments
        }
        else {
            // Read
            ko.dependencyDetection.registerDependency(observable); // The caller only needs to be notified of changes if they did a "read" operation
            return _latestValue;
        }
    }
    if (DEBUG) observable._latestValue = _latestValue;
    ko.subscribable.call(observable);
    observable.peek = function() { return _latestValue };
    observable.valueHasMutated = function () { observable["notifySubscribers"](_latestValue); }
    observable.valueWillMutate = function () { observable["notifySubscribers"](_latestValue, "beforeChange"); }
    ko.utils.extend(observable, ko.observable['fn']);

    ko.exportProperty(observable, 'peek', observable.peek);
    ko.exportProperty(observable, "valueHasMutated", observable.valueHasMutated);
    ko.exportProperty(observable, "valueWillMutate", observable.valueWillMutate);

    return observable;
}
```

**Called From:**

```
self.fraudQueue(msg.d);
```

**ViewModel**

```
function FraudQueueViewModel(runDate, analyst, fraudOid, runNumber, processed, parameter) {
    var self = this;
    self.fraudQueue = ko.observableArray();
    \\...
```

**msg.d**

Can't share true `msg.d` but is validated as valid `JSON` and `JS object`, and is an `array`.

### UPDATE 1

Error appears to be on an internal array of `msg.d`...`msg.d` contains 18 internal `arrays` of `objects`, some of which contain another internal `array`.

I created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/CWCuz/1/show) to demonstrate the issue but can't even get IE8 to open [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: If you want to use jsFiddle to test in IE8, then add `/show` onto the end up the URL and it will just render out the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my specific case the issue was *"simple"*...after debugging with IE9 running as IE8 for 6+ hours I added `domNode` to the watch list, and saw that it was failing to `appendChild`...I looked at the dom element and it was a:

```
<td data-bind="text: viewModel.functionName(property)"></td>
```

All I did was change this binding to the following:

```
<td>
    <span data-bind="text: viewModel.functionName(property)"></span>
</td>
```

Apparently IE8 has issues with binding a `function` `text` element inside a double nested `foreach` loop.  I'm not sure if this will ever help anyone else, but the important part is to debug to the issue using IE9 in IE8 mode.  This allows you to use the `Add to watch` which allows you to see the properties on your objects...then look for the node it is failing on, and *guess and pray*.

***God Speed...***

Comment: Simplified, the problem is probably caused by a faulty binding. I had a binding like `<input data-bind="text: ` that failed silently on current browsers, but IE8 would throw the error in question.

Comment: Thank you! You've saved my time too!

Answer (score 1):

As experienced through similiar circumstances to abc123, in IE8, any HTML5 element you use cannot have a text element bound to it.  For a number of elements, I had to end up replacing the html5 tag with a good old div/span tag because it would not bind to "text".